# C# Speed up parallel webrequests using async

Tags: c#, multithreading, asynchronous, parallel-processing, httpwebrequest

so I have this code:
This is the main function,a parallel for loop that iterates through all the data that needs to be posted and calls a function

```
 ParallelOptions pOpt = new ParallelOptions();
    pOpt.MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30;
    Parallel.For(0, maxsize, pOpt, (index,loopstate) => {

                    //Calls the function where all the webrequests are made
                    CallRequests(data1,data2);

                    if (isAborted)
                        loopstate.Stop();
                });
```

This function is called inside the parallel loop

```
public static void CallRequests(string data1, string data2)     
    {
        var cookie = new CookieContainer();
        var postData =  Parameters[23] + data1 +
                        Parameters[24] + data2;

        HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Parameters[25]);
        getRequest.Accept = Parameters[26];
        getRequest.KeepAlive = true;
        getRequest.Referer = Parameters[27];
        getRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
        getRequest.UserAgent = Parameters[28];
        getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
        getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
        getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
        getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
        getRequest.ContentType = Parameters[29];
        getRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
        getRequest.Timeout = 5000;
        getRequest.Proxy = null;

        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
        getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
        Stream newStream = getRequest.GetRequestStream(); //open connection
        newStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
        newStream.Close();

        HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();

        if (getResponse.Headers["Location"] == Parameters[30])
        {
            //These are simple get requests to retrieve the source code using the same format as above.
            //I need to preserve the cookie
            GetRequets(data1, data2, Parameters[31], Parameters[13], cookie);
            GetRequets(data1, data2, Parameters[32], Parameters[15], cookie);
        }
    }
```

From what I have seen and been told,I understand that making these requests async is a better idea than using a parallel loop.My method is also heavy on the proccesor.I wonder how can I make these requests async,but also preserve the multithreaded aspect. I also need to keep the cookie,after the post requests finishes.

Comment: Does https://stackoverflow.com/a/29110417/34092 help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting the `CallRequests` method to an `async` is really just a case of switching the sync method calls for async ones with the `await` keyword and changing the method signature to return `Task`.

Something like this:

```
public static async Task CallRequestsAsync(string data1, string data2)
{
    var cookie = new CookieContainer();
    var postData = Parameters[23] + data1 +
                    Parameters[24] + data2;

    HttpWebRequest getRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(Parameters[25]);
    getRequest.Accept = Parameters[26];
    getRequest.KeepAlive = true;
    getRequest.Referer = Parameters[27];
    getRequest.CookieContainer = cookie;
    getRequest.UserAgent = Parameters[28];
    getRequest.Method = WebRequestMethods.Http.Post;
    getRequest.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;
    getRequest.ProtocolVersion = HttpVersion.Version10;
    getRequest.AllowAutoRedirect = false;
    getRequest.ContentType = Parameters[29];
    getRequest.ReadWriteTimeout = 5000;
    getRequest.Timeout = 5000;
    getRequest.Proxy = null;

    byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);
    getRequest.ContentLength = byteArray.Length;
    Stream newStream =await getRequest.GetRequestStreamAsync(); //open connection
    await newStream.WriteAsync(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length); // Send the data.
    newStream.Close();

    HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)getRequest.GetResponse();

    if (getResponse.Headers["Location"] == Parameters[30])
    {
        //These are simple get requests to retrieve the source code using the same format as above.
        //I need to preserve the cookie
        GetRequets(data1, data2, Parameters[31], Parameters[13], cookie);
        GetRequets(data1, data2, Parameters[32], Parameters[15], cookie);
    }
}
```

However this, in itself, doesn't really get you anywhere because you still need to await the returned tasks in your main method. A very straightforward (if somewhat blunt) way of doing so would be to simply call `Task.WaitAll()` (or `await Task.WhenAll()` if the calling method itself is to become async). Something like this:

```
var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, maxsize).Select(index => CallRequestsAsync(data1, data2));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());
```

However, this is really pretty blunt and loses control over how many iterations are running in parallel, etc. I MUCH prefer use of the [TPL dataflow library](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/task-parallel-library-tpl) for this sort of thing. This library provides a way of chaining async (or sync for that matter) operations in parallel and passing them from one "processing block" to the next. It has a myriad of options for tweaking degrees of parallelism, buffer sizes, etc.

A detailed expose is beyond the possible scope of this answer so i'd encourage you to read up on it but one possible approach would be to simply push this to an action block - something like this:

```
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(async index =>
{
    await CallRequestsAsync(data1, data2);
}, new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 30,
    BoundedCapacity = 100,
});
for (int i=0; i <= maxsize; i++)
{
    actionBlock.Post(i); // or await actionBlock.SendAsync(i) if calling method is also async
}

actionBlock.Complete();
actionBlock.Completion.Wait(); // or await actionBlock.Completion if calling method is also async
```

Couple of additional points that are outside the scope of my answer that I should mention in passing:

1. it *looks* like your `CallRequests` method is updating some external variable with its results. Where possible it's best to avoid this pattern and have the method *return* the results for collation later (which the TPL Dataflow library handles through `TransformBlock<>`). If updating external state is unavoidable then make sure you have thought about the multithreaded implications (deadlocks, race conditions, etc.) which are outside the scope of my answer.
2. I am assuming there is some useful property of `index` which has been lost when you created a minimal description for your question? Does it index into a parameter list or something similar? If so, you can always just iterate over these directly and change the `ActionBlock<int>` to an `ActionBlock<{--whatever the type of your parameter is--}>`
3. Make sure you understand the difference between multi-threaded/parallel execution and asynchronous. There are some similarities/overlaps for sure but just making something async doesn't make it multithreaded nor is the converse true.

Comment: How can I stop making requests if using var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, maxsize).Select(index => CallRequestsAsync(data1, data2));
Task.WaitAll(tasks.ToArray());

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. `Task.WaitAll` does have an overload that takes a cancellation token but we may be at cross purposes... You do not always want to make all requests? If not, then how do you determine when to stop? If that determination is made based on results of a different ("earlier") call to `CallRequests` then how will you make the determination in parallel where they can all happen concurrently??

Comment: in my first example ( the parallel loop ) I could cancel the loop with the variable isAborted and call loopstate.Stop(); There are some cases where I dont want to make all requests,so how can I cancel them using the method you provided ?

Comment: With the `Task.WaitAll` it would be difficult (maybe even impossible) because they could, at least in theory, all be started simultaneously. I'm not at all sure I understand the execution path you are trying to achieve. What logic governs when you want to stop 'future' iterations? Even with your original example 30 iterations could be processing at once, the loopstate only stops new ones, not any in progress. I used quotes around the word 'future' because, by processing them concurrently, you (at least in part) give up control over the order of execution to process things simultaneously.

Comment: I decided to give up on the cancelation of tasks. It doesnt seem worth and safe implementing it. One final question,in the example you gave me, shouldnt the getResponse method be async? If yes, how can it be done ?

Comment: Yeah - good point. i missed that one. `HttpWebResponse getResponse = (HttpWebResponse)(await getRequest.GetResponseAsync());`

Comment: Is there a way to set a minimum number of threads using the action block method you provided ?