# Parallel vs Await vs Result - which one is better for deferred execution

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Implementation #1 - using Parallel loop**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var processes = new List<Task<object>>();

Parallel.ForEach(urls, url =>
{
  processes.Add(client.GetAsync(url).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>());
});

Task.WhenAll(processes);
```

**Implementation #2 - using async method + Result**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var processes = new List<Task<object>>();

urls.ForEach(url =>
{
  processes.Add(GetChain(client, url));
});

Task.WhenAll(processes);

async Task<object> GetChain(HttpClient client, string url)
{
  return await client.GetAsync(url).Result.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
}
```

**Implementation #3 - using async method + await**

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var processes = new List<Task<object>>();

urls.ForEach(url =>
{
  processes.Add(GetChain(client, url));
});

Task.WhenAll(processes);

async Task<object> GetChain(HttpClient client, string url)
{
  var chain = await client.GetAsync(url);
  return await chain.Content.ReadAsAsync<object>();
}
```

I like implementation #1 with Parallel loop, but there is a [possibility](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29214947/437393) that Parallel will create a new thread on each iteration and will consume more resources.

**Questions**

1. Is there a difference between these methods, can I keep using Parallel.ForEach?
2. If Parallel loop is bad, how can I improve it without creating a separate "async" method?
3. Is "await method.Result" the same as "await method1 await method2", #2 vs #3?

P.S. There are two "await" calls because HttpClient requests data, then read it asynchronously.

**Extra question - are these lines the same?**

```
method1.Result.method2                             // get result immediately
method1.ContinueWith(data => data.Result.method2)  // call both methods first
```

Comment: It's only usefull to use the Parallel.foreach if you some heavy operation to execute parallel. Adding items to a list isn't heavy. It's not usefull to mix async and parallel.

Comment: The first one (Parallel.ForEach()) just adds a useless level of parallelism. Filling the Tasks should be lightweight and fast.

Comment: Extra: Not the same. But a continuation is what you probably want, I'd have guessed.

Comment: The .Result  in example 2 kills one branch of async/await, it could even lead to a deadlock.

Comment: Perfect example for [code review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/) You should post it there.

Comment: You need to *await* the Task.WhenAll call.

Comment: Also `List<T>` is not thread safe an can not be used like in Example 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

consider the following example . it helps your to find answer on your question:

```
private static readonly List<Uri> Urls = new List<Uri>() {
    new Uri(""),
    new Uri("") };
....
Stopwatch stopwatch = new Stopwatch();
stopwatch.Start();
var result1 = Urls.Select(GetContent).ToArray();
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($@"Synchronous and NOT In Parallel:{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

stopwatch.Restart();
var result2 = Urls.AsParallel().Select(GetContent).ToArray();
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($@"Synchronous and In Parallel:{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

stopwatch.Restart();
var task1 = DoAsyncNotParallel();
task1.Wait();
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($@"Asynchronous and NOT In Parallel:{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

stopwatch.Restart();
var task2 = DoAsyncInParallel();
task2.Wait();
stopwatch.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($@"Asynchronous and In Parallel:{stopwatch.ElapsedMilliseconds}");

static async Task<string[]> DoAsyncNotParallel()
{
    List<string> content = new List<string>();
    foreach (var uri in Urls)
    {
        content.Add(await GetContentAsync(uri));
    }

    return content.ToArray();
}

static async Task<string[]> DoAsyncInParallel()
{
    var tasks = Urls.Select(uri => GetContentAsync(uri));

    var content = await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

    return content;
}
private static async Task<string> GetContentAsync(Uri uri)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.GetAsync(uri);
    var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    return content;
}


private static string GetContent(Uri uri)
{
    HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
    var response = httpClient.GetAsync(uri).Result;
    var content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    return content;
}
```

i recommend you to look through the following links which can be useful for you :

1. [Async Programming : Introduction to Async/Await on ASP.NET](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dn802603.aspx), by **Stephen Cleary**
2. [How and Where Concurrent Asynchronous I/O with ASP.NET Web API](http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/how-and-where-concurrent-asynchronous-io-with-asp-net-web-api), by Tugberk Ugurlu
3. [Parallel Programming with .NET](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/pfxteam/2012/03/24/should-i-expose-asynchronous-wrappers-for-synchronous-methods/), from Microsoft

about last part of question:

```
method1.Result.method2();
```

calling thread is blocked until method1 is completed, then method2 is being called

```
method1.ContinueWith(data => data.Result.method2());
```

calling thread is not blocked, method1 is being executed asynchronously .
once method1 is completed, then new Task is running like Task.Run(()=>{ method1.Result.method2()}). in this case method1.Result doesn't block calling thread because method1 alread completed, isCompleted=true